# Non-interactive authentication for googlesheets4 using json path

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

Although it's not my main language, I'm using R to post results from a daily ETL into a Google Sheets worksheet. Because this is going to be a scheduled job that runs in perpetuity, I'm hesitant to use the interactive flow for authenticating Google Drive from R. I have the path for my JSON from my Google Drive account credentials, but when I pass

```
gs4_deauth()
gs4_has_token()
gs4_auth(email=<email-string>, path = jsonlite::fromJSON(<path-to-json>), cache = NULL)
```

it throws the following error:

```
[1] FALSE
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
Execution halted
```

Since the error message doesn't provide much specifics, I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this or has any ideas why this could be occurring? I'm using gs4_deauth() because I had originally logged in using the interactive flow, but want to now ensure that non-interactive authentication works.

As an aside, what's the least painful way to make a token object from the json credentials file? I believe that may be simpler than repeatedly passing the json credentials directly using the `path` argument.

Answer (score 1):

In case of *service account credential*:

```r
googlesheets4::gs4_auth(
  path = "service_accout.json",
  scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
)

## NOTE: the spreadsheet is shared with the service account
s <- googlesheets4::read_sheet(ID_OF_YOUR_SPREADSHEET)
```

Token can be re-used in this way:

```r
token <- googlesheets4::gs4_token()
googledrive::drive_auth(token = token)
googledrive::drive_has_token()
[1] TRUE
```